# Add a custom javascript library in Netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: netbeans-7, javascript

I have a custom javascript library that I want to use in Netbeans, I created an HTML5 Javascript project, I can add a jQuery, ExtJS in the properties of my project but there is no way of adding a custom Javascript lib.

Any help is much apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the library manually to the html
(And copy your lib into the path ofc)

---

Edit (to low reputation):
http://forums.netbeans.org/topic20226.html even though it is for NB 6.8 it says that they are dropping the support for adding custom-libs due to the fact that it is so easy just to copy the lib manually. I would guess that this might still be valid reason for the NB-team.

Comment: Well I don't use it in an HTML file, and I don't want to copy it accross multiple projects.

Comment: Saw that tutorial but somehow those menu options are not available in 7.3.1

Comment: By the way my problem being listed as a feature request in Netbeans: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204187
That's very bad since this feature exist on all other IDEs....I guess my experience with Netbeans for Javascript will end soon....